# Assignment from incompatible pointer type when assigning an argument to a local variable

Tags: c, function, pointers, typedef

The code below returns a warning message, I can't understand why and also couldn't find an answer among questions about the same warning message. I'll thank to get the right code and the explanation about the warning message.

The warning is:

> WARNING: assignment from incompatible pointer type

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sum {
    int a,b,c;
} mytype;

mytype  sum_operation, *ptr;    


mytype sum(sum_operation) {

    ptr = &sum_operation;  

    (*ptr).a = 1;       
    (*ptr).b = 3;       

    (*ptr).c =(*ptr).b + (*ptr).a  ;

    printf("%d\n",(*ptr).c);

}

int main(){

    sum(sum_operation);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What line is the warning on?

Comment: `(*ptr).whatever` can be expressed much neater as `ptr->whatever`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function declaration should be (you omitted the parameter type):

```
mytype sum(mytype sum_operation) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mytype sum(sum_operation) {
```

Where is the type of `sum_operation`?

It might default to `int` like this. (For a reason why see @Gilles' comment and @AndreyT's answer). Of course this leads to a conflict with

```
ptr = &sum_operation;
```

which expects `sum_operation` to be of type `mytype`. So write:

```
mytype sum(mytype sum_operation) {
```

Also your function has no return statement, although it is declared to return a `mytype`.

Comment: It's not just gcc, it's a legacy from the pre-ANSI days that's still supported for backward compatibility. No type = `int`.

Comment: @Gilles: It is not "pre-ANSI". ANSI C89/90 considers this code as legal, since it supports "implicit int" rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` function is declared with an old-style K&R declaration. I.e. you declared a single parameter `sum_operation` without specifying its type. A pre-C99 compiler accepts this declaration, implicitly treating your parameter as having type `int`. This is what leads to "incompatible type" problem.

It looks like you intended your parameter to have `mytype` type. In that case you have to explicitly tell the compiler about it. Either use a modern prototype-style function declaration with explicitly specified parameter type

```
mytype sum(mytype sum_operation)
{
```

or, if you insist on old-style declaration, specify the parameter type between function header and the first `{`

```
mytype sum(sum_operation)
mytype sum_operation;
{
```

Both styles are still legal in modern C, with the former being greatly superior to the latter. Your original declaration is illegal in modern C, meaning that it might be a good idea to configure your compiler to properly catch such errors at earlier stage.